# Problems on adding RecyclerView

Tags: android

I needed the RecyclerView library in my project and I decided to add it to the list of dependencies. I've also changed the target and compile SDK versions from 29 to 27.

After compiling the app, some errors have appeared.

[image: Screenshot of a portion of the <code>app/build.gradle</code> file]

[image: Screenshot of the warning popup in Android Studio]

[image: Screenshot of the list of errors in the Build tool window in Android Studio]

[image: Screenshot of the error log in Android Studio]
Or you can just show me another way of implementing e.t.c

Comment: Please consider providing a [_Minimal, Reproducible Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code such that we can help to troubleshoot your code. Please also don't provide screenshots of your code - instead, paste the necessary code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is probably because you're using incompatible versions of the AndroidX and the former support libraries. It's either all of your dependencies from the AndroidX libraries, or use the former support libraries.

Comment: BTW, there's another reason why you shouldn't provide screenshots of your code:  It may be hard to read, especially if users have poor internet conenctivity, the image is too small/illegible and/or the hosting site of the image is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AndroidX` dependency

Update build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

Change layout file too:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView> 
... 
...
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using the former version of the RecyclerView support library.

Instead, you should be using the AndroidX RecyclerView verison of the library since you're using AndroidX libraries:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta04'
```

You should also revert back the changes you made to your target and compile SDK versions.

Check out the [releases page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview) for other release artifacts of the library.

Comment: Is it ok with 1.0.0 or better to use beta?

Comment: Depends on the stability - if you want stable dependencies, use `1.0.0`, if not, use the latest version.